# Google Firebase Cloud Functions Adding a New Google Sheet Tab

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add a new "sheet" tab in Google Sheets using Firebase Cloud Functions via Typescript. I used the tutorial 
https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/ffc4f050cc489a0280eb7f4cbe36af07 as a reference.The below code shows an example how I would like it to work. How can I make it so that I can "create" a new "sheet" tab in Google Sheet using Firebase Cloud Functions?

```
let values = [
        [
         'exampleData11','exampleData12'
        ], [
         'exampleData21','exampleData22'
        ], 
        //...
    ];

    const resource = {
        values,
    };

    await authPromise
    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        // add sheet named 'exampleSheet'
        range: 'exampleSheet',
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        resource,
    })
```

Comment: Review the Sheets API - you can't modify spreadsheet metadata - i.e. the number of sheets - with the spreadsheets.values endpoints. Instead, use [`spreadsheets.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddSheetRequest) (which is **not** `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`)

Comment: You can start by checking the [Add a sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#add_a_sheet) which adds a new sheet in a spreadsheet. Check the [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) on how to use this awesome firebase feature.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!